# Contact Form 7 и reCaptcha V3

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, contact-form7, recaptcha-v3

В форме есть такое поле

```
<input type="hidden" name="g-recaptcha-response" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-hidden" id="g-recaptcha-response">
```

Использую этот код

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=SITE_KEY"></script>
<script>
   function onClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        grecaptcha.ready(function() {
          grecaptcha.execute('SITE_KEY', {action: 'submit'}).then(function(token) {
            document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').value = token;
            console.log(document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').value);
          });
        });
      }
 </script>
```

SITE_KEY тоже есть - просто тут не показываю)))
Письмо приходит, но при отправке console.log не выводит мне токен, и в панели графиков запросов нечего не происходит.
Плагин CF7 старый и не обновляется. Нужно поставить капчу версии 3. Как почтавить капчу версии 3 на старый плагин CF7?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Послушай добрый совет - выкинь нафик капчи и используй нормальные методы для антиспама. В https://wordpress.org/plugins/la-sentinelle-antispam/ их реализовано аж 4.

Comment: reCaptcha это зло, не трать время ищи другие варианты